# Sandbox path for OS X applications

Tags: macos, sandbox

I would like to save my application's data in sandbox path where user don't have access to.

My application data could be in the form of a file or a directory.

What is the sandbox path for Mac applications? And how could I access this path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot *hide* data from the user, if that's your goal, as the app runs with the user's UID.  The sandbox path is mapped to:

```
~/Library/Containers/app-bundle-id/Data/
```

and is accessed from the sandboxed app using the [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) Foundation function, and the folder you get from this call depends on the `NSSearchPathDirectory` value you pass in.  This site has many examples of its use.

Comment: you mean to create directories /app-bundle-id/Data/ inside ~/Library/Containers/ and store my application's data in it?

Comment: Sorry, now i understood that the application should be sandboxed first. Now even if i add the application's data inside '/Users/user/Library/Containers/<App-bundle-id>/Data/Library/Application Support', they can be seen by the user right? And inside this path, i could see the shortcuts created for my desktop, downloads and so on... why are they created for?

Comment: @XiOS Yes there is no way to hide the data without encrypting it, and that can always be broken (however that would suffice for casual users).  I don't understand your comment about shortcuts; they certainly aren't created automatically AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry the path i mentioned was wrong. but the shortcuts are getting created in the path '/Users/user/Library/Containers/<App-bundle-id>/Data/'..

Comment: @XiOS I don't know why they are created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is the best to use [NSHomeDirectory()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1413045-nshomedirectory) to get the path.

Comment: I wish I could change my vote to an upvote; I realized `NSHomeDirectory()` behaves *very* differently for sandboxed apps! I'd still use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` with an appropriate constant (probably Application Support), just as with non-sandboxed apps. (I'll be able to and very happy to change to an upvote if you make any random edit, e.g. mention this distinction in function's behavior in the answer.)

Comment: I think that you can always upvote, but still thanks for the comment :).

Comment: Sadly no, it gets locked 5 minutes after the vote. (I tried to change 6min in.) "You last voted on this answer 43 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @IvanVučica I addded one space hopefully it works for you now :)